# while using google sign in and facebook sign in with my ios app - how to merge code from both viewDidLoad() methods into one?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api, google-signin

I'm implementing google sign in and facebook sign in to my ios app.

In my `viewController.swift` I have a method called `viewDidLoad()` and currently - without facebook - I have a following code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, GIDSignInUIDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad() 
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()
    print("signed in automatically")
}

}
```

and that works, all the logic with signing (with google) happens in `appDelegate` so here we only check if it's possible to sign in silently.

But now I'm following the facebook tutorial about logging in with swift on ios and the author said to modify the `viewDidLoad()` method as follows:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() == nil)
{
    print("Not logged in")
}
else
{
    print("logged in")
}

var loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
loginButton.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email"]
loginButton.delegate = self

}

}
```

Now my question is - how can I merge those two methods together, so that it works in both cases (when user uses google or when he uses facebook)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) here is line by line description of Facebook Implementation

```
if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() == nil)
{
    print("Not logged in")
}
else
{
    print("logged in")
}
```

this condition is only checking is there access token or not & printing it,if you are already loggedIn `FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()` returns access token else it will return nil

2)`var loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()`

This line initiates Facebook login Button Instance

3)`loginButton.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email"]`

sets the permission for accessing data

4)`loginButton.delegate = self`

setting the facebook delegate to self

**Conclusion** - From these lines of code only initial set up is done.So it will not get mixed up with google delegate calls.

**Solution** - you can take two separate methods for facebook & google setup.Then call them from `ViewDidLoad`.